# Query about webservices.When to use webservice?

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee

I have just started using web-services in Java and I have read all the advantages of web-services but I am still confused and want to know

1. What exactly is a web-service?
2. Why we need a web-service?
3. Situation(s) in which a web-service is needed to be used?
4. Was it introduced to replace some other technology?

Comment: Just look at wikipedia? This isn't a real programming question where Stack Overflow is all about.

Comment: Webservice Programming is also the "Programming", don't you think so? and if one doesn't have understanding of the basics , how can one build successful programs and write intelligent logics?

Comment: @BalusC consider migrating to Programmers then.

Comment: This question is off-topic here because it is not a queastion about a specific problem with code. General questions of the type "will you pplease educate me" are off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Web services is just yet another way to solve the basic problem of "how to let computer A run code on computer B".  This is just one of many ways to do that, but has some distinct advantages:

- Usually happens over a simple http-request.  This mean it is firewall friendly (if browsing works, web services will).
- Many implementations to choose from.  No vendor or technology lock-in.
- Some web services provides *contracts* in the form of a WSDL document, which allows for technology easily provide transparent uses and simulate the remote ends

The wrapping up in XML means it is a rather inefficient transport method, which may matter if you have low bandwidth or very little CPU-power.

Comment: That means if I do some project for a client, I don't have to deploy complete project on Client's computer/server .. Client can access my machine to run the application. Am I right?

Comment: Naturally computer A must be able to _reach_ computer B.  You may want to talk to your local network administrator to clarify whether that is possible.

Comment: I am not considering any hinderance, not going with details .. I am asking just to clarify the concept u just described that I got your explanation right or not.The scenario I just described full fills the definition and use of web-service or not?... n much thanks for all ur help.

Comment: Yes.  Client can reach your machine to do _work_.  This is not for complete applications, but essentially just function calls (stateless if you want to keep sane).

Answer (score 1):

**1- What exactly is a webservice?**

WebService is a component(program) deployed on a server. The main advantage of web service is that its public. Every one can use it in any language.

**2- Why we need a webservice?**

If you are preparing a simple web application Or desktop application which will be used in your private domain then you dont need to use that service.

Web Service is mainly used in case when  you want to expose your service(program) to other third party.

For example : PayBack company has a tie up with HP. On purchase of fuel of 100Rs you will get 4 payback points.

In this case, Payback will launch a web service will be used used by HP outlets. This is the real example.

So HP dont need  code for Payback points. It has to use services provided by Payback.

**3- Situation(s) in which a webservice is needed to be used?**

1> Mainly used in SOA architecture
2> If you want to expose your service to some third party then you can use it.

**4- Was it introduced to replace some other technology?**

No. Not at all. Its not replacement of any technology.

You can read [this reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_service) for further knowledge.

Comment: Thanks Gunjan for replying ..example you gave means that Payback has the code and programming logics and aaplication and HP is just accessing that application via web-service? and has no actual implementation?

Comment: Web service is no single technology. Asking whether it replaces some other tech is akin to asking whether a laptop replaces some other technology.

Comment: yes, HP is just accessing the code provided by Payback. For that HP has to generate web service client in  its required language like JAVA/.NET.

Comment: Web service is not replacing any technology. It internally uses SOAP (Simple Object  Access Protocol). It can be written in JAVA/.NET OR any technology.

Comment: Here.. main point is that it does not matter who is using that web service. Any user .NEt/JAVA/C# can use the web service by generating its client and writing a code to call that service

Comment: Gunjan, only SOAP web service uses SOAP. You are mistaking a single instance for the whole class.